# Getting precipitation data over each point in a Feature Collection in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to generate a time series chart of precipitation data using CHIRPS in Google Earth Engine. I have some twenty points over which I want the data individually, i.e, I want twenty charts.

So far, I have managed to get a single chart over all the points altogether. How can I modify the following code as per my requirements?

Link to the code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/f38eca09db9e303f69d5a69e9d863a0a

```
//Filter image collection
var precip = chirps.filterDate('2000-01-01','2008-12-31');

//Create and print rainfall chart
print(ui.Chart.image.series(precip.limit(5000),tunga,ee.Reducer.mean(),1000).setOptions({

title: 'gp_1: PPT time series',
hAxis: {title: 'Day'},
vAxis:{title:'rainfall (mm/day)'}
}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to generate multiple charts, you have to do this “on the client side”, in the JavaScript code itself, rather than sending a single request to Earth Engine. In order to do this specifically for all points in your `FeatureCollection`, you use the `evaluate` operation to download enough information to do that:

```
tunga.select([]).evaluate(function (featureCollection) {
  featureCollection.features.forEach(function (feature) {
    // Do something with each feature here.
  });
});
```

1. `tunga.select([])` discards all the properties of the features. This is because we only need the ID and the geometry, which will always be present. (If your features had a property which you wanted to use to label the charts, you would put its name in the brackets here.)
2. `.evaluate(...)` tells Earth Engine to compute the result — i.e. the collection without any properties — and download it for use, in GeoJSON format. It takes a callback function because the computation may take a while to complete.
3. `featureCollection` is *not* an `ee.FeatureCollection` — it is a plain data structure, which we can access using JavaScript functionality. In particular, we'll write `featureCollection.features.forEach(...)` to loop over each of the features in the collection.
4. Within the inner function/loop, `feature` is the individual feature. Again, this is a GeoJSON feature structure, not an Earth Engine object, so we can access the contents directly. In particular, it has `feature.geometry` (which we can use to generate the chart) and `feature.id` (which we can use to label which chart this is).

Filling in the middle with your chart code, we get this (https://code.earthengine.google.com/7a58159ebd13fbcd32f136b7213e43f9):

```
tunga.select([]).evaluate(function (featureCollection) {
  featureCollection.features.forEach(function (feature) {
    print(
      ui.Chart.image.series(
        precip.limit(5000),
        ee.Geometry(feature.geometry),
        ee.Reducer.mean(),
        1000)
      .setOptions({
        title: 'gp_1: PPT time series ' + feature.id,
        hAxis: {title: 'Day'},
        vAxis:{title:'rainfall (mm/day)'}
      }));
  });
});
```

Note the `ee.Geometry(...)` cast to convert the GeoJSON geometry back into an `ee.Geometry` object.

If we wanted to do more complex processing with each feature, it would be wise to, instead of re-uploading each part of the feature that we need to use, look up the feature by ID in the collection (using, perhaps, `ee.FeatureCollection.filter().first()`) but that is not necessary for this case.

Comment: Thanks a bunch; this saved me. :)